# Starling: RenderTexture performance issue on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, performance, flash, starling-framework

I have a game, which runs at 30 fps on iphone 5 (iOS 6.12) because of lots of objects. That's fine.

Then I instanciate a RenderTexture (Starling) and that freezes the game because it draws 200 times - that's also fine.

BUT, when the RenderTexture changes position on screen, fps drops to 5 fps. When it stops moving, it goes back to 30. No drawing is performed while moving - only change the y-value.

What can possibly cause this? The starling documentation says that RenderTexture should act like a normal texture once drawn.

Comment: did you figure it out?